# How to update values of a specific custom field for every woocommerce product at once

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, custom-fields

I want to update a value to a specific custom field in all Woocommerce products at once.
But this is not working

```
function update_products_by_x(){
    $products_ids = get_posts( array(
        'post_type'        => 'product', // or ['product','product_variation'],
        'post_status'      => 'publish',
        'fields'           => 'ids'
    ) );

    foreach ( $products_ids as $product_id ) {
        $product = wc_get_product($product_id); 
        update_post_meta($product_id, 'field_name_here', esc_attr('field_value_here'));
    }
}
add_action('wp_footer', 'update_products_by_x');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `WP_Query` to retrieve all products and hook your function to `init`:

```
add_action('init', 'update_products_by_x');
function update_products_by_x(){
    if(isset($_GET['update_woo_products'])){
        $args = array(
            'post_type'      => 'product',
            'posts_per_page' => -1,
            'post_status' => 'publish',
        );

        $loop = new WP_Query( $args );

        while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();
            global $product;
            update_post_meta($product->ID, 'field_name_here', esc_attr('field_value_here'));
        endwhile;

        wp_reset_query();
        die('done');
    }
}
```

If you notice there is a small condition to make sure that this only run if requested, so to run this function you'd need to visit the website and make sure you add the parameter `update_woo_products` as a query string (eg: https://example.com/?update_woo_products=1 )

This will run the function and show a white page with the message `done`, which means that the condition was met and the function was executed successfully.