# Bulk update specific custom field on All Products in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce

I want to update a custom fileds value for all products, inspiring [this article](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57529558/how-to-update-values-of-a-specific-custom-field-for-every-woocommerce-product-at) , I writed the following function. And I expect to update all values after refreshing the website, based on price of product. It does not change any value.

```
function update_my_metadata(){
   $args = array(
        'post_type' => 'product', 
        'post_status' => 'publish', 
        'posts_per_page'   => -1 
    );
    $posts = get_posts($args);
    foreach ( $posts as $post ) {
        $product_att = wc_get_product ( $post->ID );
        $price_to_use = $product_att->get_price();
        $unit_to_use = $product_att->get_meta( 'custom_text_field_unit' );
        $unit_touse_esc = custom_field_options_unit()[$unit_to_use];
        $currency = get_woocommerce_currency_symbol();
        $amount_to_use = $product_att->get_meta( 'rasa_store_product_ppu_number' );
        $calculation = round( $price_to_use/$amount_to_use, 2) ;
        $english_format_number = number_format($calculation, 2, '.', '');
        $rasa_price_per_unit_spanish_club = $english_format_number . ' ' . $currency . $unit_touse_esc ;
        $product = wc_get_product( $post->ID ); // get the product Object
        update_post_meta( $product, 'price_per_kg', $rasa_price_per_unit_spanish_club);
    }
}
add_action('init','update_my_metadata');
```

Please if you have any ideas about the section I made a mistake, please give me some tips to fix my function.

Update:
I change `update_post_meta( $product, 'price_per_kg', $rasa_price_per_unit_spanish_club);` to `update_post_meta( $product, 'price_per_kg', '1234');` but it does not change the value to 1234, it seems the problem is related to the structure of code.

Comment: Thanks, as you mentioned, I changed the value to 1234, and refresh the site, But it does not update the value, and still I see old values.

Comment: Change `update_post_meta( $product,` to `update_post_meta( $post->ID,`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is `update_post_meta( $product,` that should required to be: 
`update_post_meta( $post->ID,'price_per_kg', $rasa_price_per_unit_spanish_club);`

I have revisited your code, using CRUD methods and changing of hook for a front end more generic hook, and allowing an update by steps of 250 products.

Also, I use a better WC_Product_Query instead of a WP_Query, that allow to query only the products that haven't been updated yet.

You can use `wc_price()` WooCommerce price formatting function, stripping all HTML tags.

The code below, will only work when an "administrator" will browse a frontend page of your website. Each time, 250 products will be processed (to avoid breaking your site) and the number of processed products will be displayed in the footer (only visible to the admins). When the number of processed products will be below 250, that will mean that all products have been processed.

If `250` processed products by step is too much or not enough, you can change `'limit' => 250` to something more convenient.

The code:

```php
add_action('wp_footer', 'bulk_update_product_custom_metadata');
function bulk_update_product_custom_metadata(){
    // Only admins on front end
    if ( ! current_user_can('administrator') ) return;

    // Using WC_Product_Query
    $products = wc_get_products( array(
        'status'       => 'publish',
        'price_per_kg' => 'NOT EXISTS', 
        'limit'        => 250,
    ) );
    
    $count = 0; // Initializing
     
    foreach ( $products as $product ) {
        $price_to_display = (float) wc_get_price_to_display($product);
        $unit_text        = custom_field_options_unit()[$product->get_meta('custom_text_field_unit')];
        $ppu_number       = (float) $product->get_meta('rasa_store_product_ppu_number');
        $price_per_kg     = wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price($price_to_display/$ppu_number) ) . $unit_text;

        $product->update_meta_data('price_per_kg', $price_per_kg ); // update
        $product->save(); // save
        $count++;
    }
    // Footer message
    printf('<div><pre>%s Product(s) have been processed…</pre></div>', $count);
}

// Add "price_per_kg" meta query to wc product query
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_price_per_kg_query_var', 10, 2 );
function handle_price_per_kg_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['price_per_kg'] ) ) {
        if( in_array( esc_attr($query_vars['price_per_kg']), array('EXISTS', 'NOT EXISTS') ) ) {
            $query['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => 'price_per_kg',
                'compare' => esc_attr($query_vars['price_per_kg']),
            );
        } else {
            $query['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'   => 'price_per_kg',
                'value' => esc_attr($query_vars['price_per_kg']),
            );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

It should work.

---

Addition *(as demanded by OP in comments section)*

To query products added in last 7 days use:

```php
    // Using WC_Product_Query
    $products = wc_get_products( array(
        'status'       => 'publish',
        'price_per_kg' => 'NOT EXISTS', 
        'limit'        => 250,
        'date_created' => '>' . date("Y-m-d", strtotime("-7 days")),
    ) );
```

---

**Addition 2:** Updating again the price per Kg (untested)

```php
// Each time you want to update all your products, you increase the number below (once)
function per_kg_updated(){
    return '1'; 
}


add_action('wp_footer', 'bulk_update_product_custom_metadata');
function bulk_update_product_custom_metadata(){
    // Only admins on front end
    if ( ! current_user_can('administrator') ) return;

    // Using WC_Product_Query
    $products = wc_get_products( array(
        'status'       => 'publish',
        'per_kg_updated' => per_kg_updated(), 
        'limit'        => 250,
    ) );
    
    $count = 0; // Initializing
     
    foreach ( $products as $product ) {
        $price_to_display = (float) wc_get_price_to_display($product);
        $unit_text        = custom_field_options_unit()[$product->get_meta('custom_text_field_unit')];
        $ppu_number       = (float) $product->get_meta('rasa_store_product_ppu_number');
        $price_per_kg     = wp_strip_all_tags( wc_price($price_to_display/$ppu_number) ) . $unit_text;

        $product->update_meta_data('price_per_kg', $price_per_kg ); // update
        $product->update_meta_data('per_kg_updated', per_kg_updated() ); // Tag Updated
        $product->save(); // save
        $count++;
    }
    // Footer message
    printf('<div><pre>%s Product(s) have been processed…</pre></div>', $count);
}

// Add "price_per_kg" meta query to wc product query
add_filter( 'woocommerce_product_data_store_cpt_get_products_query', 'handle_per_kg_updated_query_var', 10, 2 );
function handle_per_kg_updated_query_var( $query, $query_vars ) {
    if ( ! empty( $query_vars['per_kg_updated'] ) ) {
        if( in_array( esc_attr($query_vars['per_kg_updated']), array('EXISTS', 'NOT EXISTS') ) ) {
            $query['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => 'per_kg_updated',
                'compare' => esc_attr($query_vars['per_kg_updated']),
            );
        } else {
            $query['meta_query'][] = array(
                'key'     => 'per_kg_updated',
                'value'   => esc_attr($query_vars['per_kg_updated']),
                'compare' => '!=',
            );
        }
    }
    return $query;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @LoicTheAztec , As always, you saved me. In `wc_get_products( array(` can I put an array for the date, for example, only update products added in last 7 days?

Comment: I have added an addition for that at then end of the answer.

Comment: Is it possible to edit products in a group of 250? I use `'limit'        => 250,` and it works, but if I increase that to 1500, the server stops working. I just thinking about updating in group of 250. for example: product 1 to product 250, and a few minutes later product 251 to 500, and etc

Comment: My code is already doing that by batch of 250 products each time (by group of 250 products if you prefer). All products processed are tagged with `price_per_kg` as meta data, so they don't show up again in the next batch.

Comment: My problem is that in half of my products, some data already exists in `price_per_kg`, and I want to replace these data with this new calculation. I just thinking about removing `'price_per_kg' => 'NOT EXISTS'` to check all products. can I add an array to 'limit' to check only special range?

Comment: Currently, I am using `'date_created' => '2023-02-01...2023-03-01'` to edit based on date ranges and reduce the process, but I think if it is possible to jump based on batch of 250 it will be much more interesting.

Comment: I have added an addition for updates (untested).